# density and An Accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be topological space and $A,B\subset X$ ,

The derived of A is 
$A'=\{ x\in X \mid \ x \mbox{  is an accumulation point of } A \} $h

why 
$B   \mbox{ is dense in } A \iff A  \subset \overline{B} \underset{\mbox{why } }{\iff  } \forall x\in A\mid x\in B^{'}$

for example: 
$Q   \mbox{ is dense in } R \iff R\subset \overline{\ {Q}} \underset{\mbox{why } }{\iff  } \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\in \mathbb{Q}^{'}$

- My question could someone show me why we have that equivalence ?

Comment: The results follow from the equality $\overline{A}=A \cup A' $ for some subset $A$ of $X$.

Comment: couldyou point me on some reference to se that equality please Thanks in advaced

Comment: You can check *Topology* by *James Munkres, 2nd Edition,* $Theorem.17.6$ page 97.